# How to set custom test execution order for a test suite in JUnit5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I have a large set of tests on JUnit5, which I run in parallel in several threads.
There is also information about the time of each test.
I want to run at the beginning of the longest tests, and leave the fastest at the end to optimize common execution time.

I have not found a way to do this in JUnit5.

In version `5.4` there is an `org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer` interface which allows you to write a test sorter within a test class. And connect to the test class via the annotation `org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder`.

I would like something similar, but globally, for the whole test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is unfortunately not currently possible in JUnit 5 (i.e., either on the JUnit Platform or within JUnit Jupiter).

There is however an [open issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1838) dedicated to this topic. So feel free to chime in there.

Answer (score 10):

It is now possible to order test classes in JUnit 5 (since [v5.8.0](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/release-notes/)).

*src/test/resources/***junit-platform.properties**:

```
# ClassOrderer$OrderAnnotation sorts classes based on their @Order annotation
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$OrderAnnotation
```

Other Junit built-in class orderer implementations:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$ClassName
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$DisplayName
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random
```

For other ways (beside *junit-platform.properties* file) to set configuration parameters refer [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params).

You can also provide your own orderer. It must implement *ClassOrderer* interface:

```
package foo;
public class MyOrderer implements ClassOrderer {
    @Override
    public void orderClasses(ClassOrdererContext context) {
        Collections.shuffle(context.getClassDescriptors());
    }
}
```

```
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=foo.MyOrderer
```

#### Note that `@Nested` test classes cannot be ordered by a *ClassOrderer*.

Refer to JUnit 5 [documentations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#class-order) and *ClassOrderer* [api docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer.html) to learn more about ordering test classes.